# Grafo de fluxo de controle

Tags: engenharia-de-software

Estou com dúvidas na parte de **Grafo de Fluxo de Controle**.
É pedido para o código abaixo o grafo de fluxo de controle.

[image: exemplo de código]

Eu fiz dessa maneira:

[image: Foto com um grafo]

- **Aquele nodo 7 é realmente necessário?**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exercício 2 que comentei:

Comment: Eu acho que tanto do 4 quanto do 5 voltaria para 2...

Comment: Agora, claro, ficaria mais legível 4 e 5 indo pro 6, e o 6 indo pro 2, sem precisar do 7. Aparentemente aí nesse gráfico de fluxo o 6 seria um "no-op" do seu algoritmo acima

Comment: Então aquele 7 poderia ser descartado sem problemas?... Eu tenho outro exercício que o código é bem parecido com esse ,só que na parte do while há duas condições que é assim: while((a<0) or (b<-2)) , nesse caso eu teria de separar cada condição do while em um nó novo? (vou ver se posto o print do exercício).